Example on how to sink to a file Flink 1.20
I am trying to get an example on how I can sink to a file bit all I get its deprecated. The flink documentation doesn't help cos all I get is deprecated.
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try 
    {
        // Set up the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // Define the input data path

        DataStream<String> text = env.fromElements("Nathan", "Noah", "Olivia", "Emily", "Nathaniel");

        DataStream < String > filtered = text.filter(new FilterFunction < String > ()
            {
                public boolean filter(String value) {
                return value.startsWith("N");
            }
        });
        DataStream < Tuple2 < String, Integer >> tokenized = filtered.map(new Tokenizer());

        DataStream < Tuple2 < String, Integer >> counts = tokenized
            .keyBy(value -> value.f0)
            .sum(1);

        DataStream<String> result = counts.map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String map(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) {
                return value.f0 + ": " + value.f1;
            }
        });

        //result.print();

        result.writeAsText("/Users/T/Repos/FlinkPOC/src/main/java/com/poc/flink/Output.txt");

        
    
        // Execute the Flink job
        env.execute("Word Count Example with datastreams");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
         // Print stack trace to diagnose errors
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

in this code snippet  result.writeAsText and env.fromElements are deprecated. I am using Flink 1.20.0

The replacement for fromElements is fromData -- see the docs for details, but
env.fromData("Nathan", "Noah", "Olivia", "Emily", "Nathaniel");

should get the job done.
For the sink, you want to use the FileSink. This is  not a drop-in replacement for writeAsText. writeAsText was not a production-ready sink -- it was only suitable for small scale testing -- and we don't want to carry it forward into Flink 2.0. See the docs linked above for an example, but you'll need to do something like this:
final FileSink<String> sink = FileSink
    .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
    .withRollingPolicy(
        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
            .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
            .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .withMaxPartSize(MemorySize.ofMebiBytes(1024))
            .build())
    .build();

result.sinkTo(sink);

However, you'll want to adjust the format, rollover policy, etc. to meet your needs.
